# How can I change parent state in two children components using Hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a Manager component which is parent and has state of mode.
It conditionally renders two diffrent components related to their state,
I want when user clicks on Add button in child component , the state of parent changes.
also vica versa for the other sibling component.
can you help me to solve my proble , I mean how should I change parent state in children components with clicking on button.

if you help me in one children i will do the same for other one.

this is  parent component :

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import BasePage from './BasePage'
import AddRecordForm from './AddRecordForm'

function Manager() {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('base-page');
    
    function handleChangePageClick(Mode) {
        setMode(Mode);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My PhoneBook</h1>
            {mode === 'base-page' ? <BasePage onClick = {handleChangePageClick} /> : <AddRecordForm onClick = {handleChangePageClick} />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Manager
```

and this is one of its children :

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import Manager from './Manager'

function BasePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <fieldset>
        <legend>Search</legend>
        <input placeholder = "Enter name to search" type = "text" />
    </fieldset>
            <br />
        <button onClick>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BasePage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the handler you're passing to the child, something like this:

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import Manager from './Manager'

function BasePage({ onClick }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <fieldset>
        <legend>Search</legend>
        <input placeholder = "Enter name to search" type = "text" />
    </fieldset>
            <br />
        <button onClick={() => onClick('add-record-form')}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BasePage
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an onClick event to the component like you're doing here:

```
<BasePage onClick={handleChangePageClick} />
```

pass down the function as a prop:

```
<BasePage handleClick={handleChangePageClick} />
```

The child component can then call that function `onClick`:

```
function BasePage({ handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Search</legend>
        <input placeholder = "Enter name to search" type = "text" />
      </fieldset>
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use the [useContext](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook or a callback function given by the parent in the props.
For the useContext hook, it will put a data available for the component and all of his children.

Also by vice versa, rendering a parent component will automatically re-render the child component.

This [link](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/) will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I have to use useState and useEffect only,

Comment: Then i guess you need to use a callBack function that change the parent state and pass it to your child component throught the props.